# PHP: List root's crontab with sudo

Tags: php, exec, cron, sudo

Using PHP I would like to be able to list root's crontab.
I am able to run the following command as the Apache user from the command line and get the desired result:

```
sudo crontab -l
```

however, in my PHP I have the following command which does not work and returns an empty set:

```
exec('sudo crontab -l', $out);
print_r($out);
```

Is it environmental? Or permissions?

I have also tried `shell_exec()` `system()` and `passthru()`

Also, note that I have disabled SELinux and added Apache to the sudoers file so that it does not need to be prompted for a password.

Comment: This might be better in the serverfault.stackexchange.com forum.

Comment: What does `echo \`whoami\`, "\n";` tells you?

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: is the apache user in the sudoers file? PHP won't know what to do with the password prompt sudo pops up if not.

Comment: whoami returns apache, and apache was added to the sudoers file: `apache  ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD:   ALL`

Comment: Überscary.  Are you sure you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: Even though I had set error reporting on, you must redirect the output of the command like so:

```
exec('sudo crontab -l 2>&1', $out);
var_dump($out);
```

After setting this, I found the following error:

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

Following research of the issue, the resolution is to edit the sudoers file and comment out: #Default requiretty.

http://www.zimbra.com/forums/installation/10553-solved-sudo-sorry-you-must-have-tty-run-sudo.html

I apologize as I got further into this issue, it became less of a PHP issue and more of unix system question.